# Regexp to match multiline sections starting with identifier up to an end identifier

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

How to write a regexp that will match all the multi line sections (with different amount of lines) that start with a given identifier (Until receiving an end of message keyword).

Example -
I want to extract all sections that start with keyword 'START' up until 'END_OF_MSG' from a given text block:

```
HELLO
START ABC DEF GHI JKL
QWER RANDOM TEXT 213%@#!
UIOP RANDOMZXCVB123456
START ABC DEF GHI JKL
ZZZZZ RANDOMTEXT213%@#!
11111 RANDOMZXCVB123456
$$$$$$ SOMEMORETEXT
START ABC DEF GHI JKL
QWER RANDOMTEXT213%@#!
$$$$$ RANDOMZXCVB123456
END_OF_MSG
```

I'd like the regexp to produce three sections:

```
START ABC DEF GHI JKL
QWER RANDOM TEXT 213%@#!
UIOP RANDOMZXCVB123456
```

```
START ABC DEF GHI JKL
ZZZZZ RANDOMTEXT213%@#!
11111 RANDOMZXCVB123456
$$$$$$ SOMEMORETEXT
```

```
START ABC DEF GHI JKL
QWER RANDOMTEXT213%@#!
$$$$$ RANDOMZXCVB123456
```

So far i've worked out a regexp which seems to do this **almost** correctly

```
(?m)^START(.|\n)*?((?=^START)|END_OF_MSG)
```

The issue is, that the last section also includes the END_OF_MSG identifier which i'd like to skip.
I also think that this regexp does not look like the most optimal way of grabbing those sections. Any ideas on how to improve this?

Example available here: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/648Ep2/1/)

Comment: You should replace `((?=^START)|END_OF_MSG)` with `(?=^(?:START|END_OF_MSG))`. Also, replace `(.|\n)*?` with `.*?` and add `(?s)` at the start of the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match `START` followed by the rest of the line, and match all following lines that do not start with `START` of `END_OF_MSG` using a negative lookahead.

```
^START\b.*(?:\R(?!START\b|END_OF_MSG\b).*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `START\b.*` Match START, a word boundary and the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\R` Match a newline sequence
  - `(?!START\b|END_OF_MSG\b).*` Match the whole line if it does not start with any of the alternatives using a negative lookahead
- `)*` Close the group and repeat it 0+ times to match all the lines

In Java with doubled backslashes

```
^START\\b.*(?:\\R(?!START\\b|END_OF_MSG\\b).*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2QR10N/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/hRvoQZ)